# Calling one service from another service in gwt

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

We have a GWT + GAE app and here is the situation:

We have two different forms/pages:

1. Register as a Blood Donor
2. Register as a Eye Donor

Till now we had underlying two different entry point classes which calls two different services one implemented as RegisterBloodDonorServiceImpl  and another as RegisterEyeDonorServiceImpl.

Now, we want to implement a feature where we want to give option to the blood donor to register as eye donor as well. As the data is almost same so we dont want the end user to fill two forms and instead just provide a checkbox to achieve the same on the blood donor form.

So, now the question is how should we implement it?

1. Should we call the RegisterEyeDonorServiceImpl from inside the RegisterBloodDonorServiceImpl after blood donor data is persisted in the service? If yes then we are not sure how to call one service from another service?
2. Should we invoke two services one after another in the entrypoint implementing class?
3. Any better idea ?

Comment: By "Service", do you mean GWT RPC Services?

Comment: yes GWT RPC service which use the format of defining MySync.java and MyAsync.java and impl as MyServiceImpl.java structure

Comment: Are does services in the same application? If that's the case, you should directly invoke the classes without passing through RPC

Comment: yes both are in the same application. Though I was thinking if this is the nice way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where we've had code in our project that needs to be called from more than one service, we've found it best to extract the code from our `*ServiceImpl` classes and into its own class. Then each service can hold its own instance of this class as required.

So in your case, I would recommend creating a class with a name such as `EyeDonorServiceCalls` with a method like `registerEyeDonor`. `RegisterEyeDonorServiceImpl` will keep an instance of this class and call `registerEyeDonor` when it receives an appropriate service call. `RegisterBloodDonorServiceImpl` will keep another instance and call `registerEyeDonor` as part of the registration for blood donors if the appropriate check box has been ticked.

Comment: hi just to double sure so you mean something like moving out the entire functionality of eye donor registation to a new class and in the eye donor service impl just calling this class by creating and instance and same way doing that from bloodDonorImpl class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the extreme case your *Impl class will have almost no code in it, just calls to the new class. In our solution though the services still take care of authentication, and they are responsible for creating and closing the database connections, which makes our code easier to test. You should do what works best for you!